# SQL Procedures Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

I want to write a procedure that takes two dates as input (a duration) and updates the commission amount of every weekly report for which the start date falls under this duration. The commission amount is the result of multiplication of sale amount and commission rate (%).

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateweekly_sales_report
(p_start IN WEEKLY_SALES_REPORT.StartDate%TYPE, p_end IN 
weekly_sales_report.EndDate%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE WEEKLY_SALES_REPORT SET ComAmount = SaleAmount*ComRate where 
(StartDate-EndDate) = (p_start- p_end);
SELECT concat('The commission amount for report ',ReportID,' has been updated 
to ',ComAmount,' dollars, 
which is',ComRate,'% of the total sale amount of ',SaleAmount,' dollars.')
COMMIT;
END;
/
BEGIN
   updateweekly_sales_report('2018-04-02','2018-04-08');
END;
/
```

I have two errors 
LINE/COL ERROR

---

6/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Comment: What's that lonely `SELECT concat...` (with no target and no trailing `;`) supposed to do? And you're aware that `WHERE (StartDate-EndDate) = (p_start- p_end)` will match all rows where the **difference** of the dates is equal (which is supposedly all, if you're not having all weeks with a different number of days...)?

Comment: what type of database are you using? (Oracle, sqlServer, etc)

Answer (score 0):

`'2018-04-02'` and `'2018-04-08'` are character strings, not dates. To pass in an actual `DATE` type you'll need to use the `TO_DATE` function to convert your strings to dates:

```
BEGIN
  updateweekly_sales_report(TO_DATE('2018-04-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                            TO_DATE('2018-04-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
END;
```

Or you can use a date literal:

```
BEGIN
  update_weekly_sales_report(DATE '2018-04-02',
                             DATE '2018-04-08');
END;
```

Best of luck.